# What protocols of tkinter toplevel widget are there

Tags: python, tkinter, protocols, toplevel

When using Tk.protocol arguments could be
“WM_DELETE_WINDOW”, “WM_SAVE_YOURSELF” and “WM_TAKE_FOCUS”

But is there any else.

Concretely, in my program, I want to create a window that follows another window

```
root = Tk()
root.config(width = 100, height = 100
a = Tk()
a.overredirect()
#here I just make window stand below bottom left corner of original window
#I succeded in doing that, but it is not ellegant at all and partially functional
#does anybody knows how to do it better
#note: this is not the main problem
a.geometry('%ix40+%s+%s' % (180,
                            int(g[g.index('+')+1:g.rindex('+')]) + 8,
                            int(g[g.rindex('+')+1:]) + 51 +
                            int(g[g.index('x')+1:g.index('+')])))
```

and here I should make "a" follow "root" if root moves on the screen

My actual question what other protocols are there or where can I find them all

Comment: what you want is a binding and not a protocol. You can use the  `<Configure>` event to track the window and have another window follow. It will take a bit of tracking but should be simple enough to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer you are looking for :

> Q. Is there a way of getting a list of available protocols for wm
>   protocol? The man pages only list the obvious / common ones
>   (WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_SAVE_YOURSELF, and WM_TAKE_FOCUS).
>
> A. Those are the only three defined by the ICCCM; the freedesktop.org
>   [EWMH] spec also defines _NET_WM_PING.
>
> Note that WM_SAVE_YOURSELF is deprecated, and Tk apps can't implement
>   WM_TAKE_FOCUS or _NET_WM_PING correctly, so WM_DELETE_WINDOW is the
>   only one that should be used.
>
> DKF: Tk now handles _NET_WM_PING for you by itself in the correct way;
>   you'll never see this one at the script level. (The purpose of the
>   protocol is to let other clients — especially a window manager or
>   session manager — determine positively whether the application is
>   processing events. That puts its implementation correctly buried in
>   the guts of Tk.)

Source : https://wiki.tcl.tk/8454