# How will I make a tk window which cannot be minimized in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried `win.overrideredirect(True)` it didn't work...

My Code goes like this:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.resizable(0,0)
win.wm_protocol("WM_SAVE_YOURSELF", lambda: print("On exit"))
Label(win, text="Tk Window").pack()
win.mainloop()
```

**Specs:
Python 3.9.6 [Latest],
Pip 21.1.3,
OS: Windows 10 Home**

I want to make the minimize button to be disabled...
Please help

Comment: _"it didn't work..."_ - that's very vague. Why do you think it didn't work? What happened when you did it?

Comment: `WM_SAVE_YOURSELF` is deprecated. *WM_DELETE_WINDOW* should work.

Comment: @Atlas435 Can you please tell me your source? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50630990/11106801) which links to [this](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wm+protocol) but it doesn't say that it's deprecated. I am thinking of using it in one of my projects so I want to know if it's deprecated.

Comment: @Atlas435 I have tried both and *WM_DELETE_WINDOW* is to prevent the window from closing... But I want to disable the functionality of minimize button... I have searched all over the internet but could not find anything relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing @N1CK145 posted didn't work for me but I am guessing that he/she tried to do this:

```py
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-toolwindow", True)
root.mainloop()
```

If you want to know more `attribute` options look [here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wm+attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969870/removing-minimize-maximize-buttons-in-tkinter):

```py
import Tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

root.title("wm min/max")

# this removes the maximize button
root.resizable(0,0)

# # if on MS Windows, this might do the trick,
# # but I wouldn't know:
# root.attributes(toolwindow=1)

# # for no window manager decorations at all:
# root.overrideredirect(1)
# # useful for something like a splash screen

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "root.attributes(toolwindow=1)" giving an error TypeError: wm_attributes() got an unexpected argument 'toolwindow'

Comment: @HimangshuDe try only this line `root.resizable(0,0)`

Comment: I also did that but that didn't work... I want to completely disable functioning of minimize button in the window manager decoration

Comment: @HimangshuDe Try `root.attributes("-toolwindow", True)`. It worked for me.

Comment: @TheLizzard Voila, that's working, Thanks... You may post your answer in the answer section!

Comment: I need a window that is resizable, maximizable, and closable, but not minimizable (to cut down on confusion when this window must be closed and is blocking other things), so I tried the 'toolwindow' idea, but then no icon is placed in the taskbar and I found many ways to lose the window on my screen and not be able to find it again (i.e. it didn't solve the problem of reducing confusion).  In the end I used a binding that catches the '<Unmap>' call, but the window still minimizes and I deiconify it if it becomes unviewable (minimized).  It's very kludgy and I'm searching for something better.

Answer (score 0):

try resizeable function like this :

```
win= Tk()

win.geometry("750x250")

win.resizable(False, False)
```